# Make all fields or some of required by passing options to schema

Tags: javascript, joi

I am using `Joi` for validating body data.

So, If I have an API which creates vehicles.
I would create an schema like below.

```
const validateUserVehicleData = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string(),
    odometer_count: Joi.number().allow(null),
    registration_number: Joi.string(),
    current_milage: Joi.number(),
    last_service_date: Joi.date(),
    last_service_km: Joi.number(),
    chassis_num: Joi.string(),
    engine_num: Joi.string(),
    vehicle_id: Joi.string(),
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};
```

I know I can do here `vehicle_id: Joi.string().required()` to make them *individually* required.

But I want make some fields to be required by passing dynamically data to schema object.

Like, If I want to make only few of them required like below.

```
//It should make registration_number and currrent_mileage required
const schema = Joi.object({..}).required(['registration_number', 'currrent_mileage ']); // I know this doesn't exist but if there is any workaround
```

I also tried something like below to make all of them required, but it is not working neither throwing any error.

```
// It should make all fields required
const schema = Joi.object({..}).required();
```

*One thing I can do here creating multiple schema for same data, which is working fine.*

But ended up creating three to four schema for validating same data.

Is there any work around here? I went through doc, but I couldn't find any thing like these.

*Update*

For validating all fields, I found a work around.

```
Joi.object({
    registration_number: Joi.string(),
    vehicle_id: Joi.string(),
    .....
}).options({presence: 'required'})
```

Comment: since you found the solution, I think you should post an answer as well

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, I still need another part to be answered.

Comment: Checkout @saurabh answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64926218/10205844) It's quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

To pick required keys, use `and` method

According to the [docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md) of `object.and(...peers, [options])`:

Defines an all-or-nothing relationship between keys where if one of the peers is present, all of them are required as well where:

- `peers` - the string key names of which if one present, all are required.
  options
- `optional settings`:

  - `separator` - overrides the default . hierarchy separator. Set to false to treat the key as a literal value.

```js
const schema = Joi.object({ ... }).and("registration_number", "current_mileage");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work the way I want. It will bind them together, one can not exist without other. But I want that control for individual field with no dependency on one another. Same is for `.with()`

Comment: But it also creates dependency. If I use `.with()` I can't have `registration_number` without `current_mileage`.